# "Method Not Allowed" exception while executing CreateChangesetAsync of TfvcClient

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I work in a quite big organisation and we are facing a problem since we needed to migrate one of our solution.

To sum up, we have an internal tool that browse or old **TFS 2013** server and parse several csproj and config files to update some of there content to be able to migrate our sites to *IIS10*.

The previous solution, which was using NuGet packages *Machado.Microsoft.TeamFoundation* and *Machado.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.client* (**now obsolete**) and was no more working well.

It was decided to migrate our solution to "**Microsoft.TeamFoundation**" NuGet packages. Everything is going well instead the check-in part.

```
private TfvcChangesetRef Checkin(TfvcItem item, string newContent)
{
    // Establish a connection using Windows Credentials
    using (var connection = TfsHelper.GetConnection())
    // Create TFS Client
    using (var tfvcClient = connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>())
    {
        item.ContentMetadata = new FileContentMetadata();

        var changeset = new TfvcChangeset();
        var tfvcChange = new TfvcChange(item, versionControlChangeType.Edit);
        tfvcChange.NewContent = new ItemContent();
        tfvcChange.NewContent.Content = newContent;
        tfvcChange.NewContent.ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText;
        tfvcChange.Item.Path = item.Path;

        var changesList = new List<TfvcChange>();
        changesList.Add(tfvcChange);
        changeset.Author = new IdentityRef();
        changeset.Changes = changesList;
        changeset.Comment = "This is a test";

        return tfvcClient.CreateChangesetAsync(changeset).Result;
    }
}
```

The `TfsHelper.GetConnection()` is defined:

```
public static VssConnection GetConnection()
{
    var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TfsUri"]), new VssAadCredential());

    connection.ConnectAsync().SyncResult();

    // Correctly contains the AAD user account
    return connection;
}
```

The application is breaking while calling the `tfvcClient.CreateChangesetAsync(changeset)` with a changeset composed of:

```
Changes          Count = 1 (Correct, one change to be checked in)
Comment          "This is a test"
Author           typeof(IdentifyRef)
Other values     Default ones.
```

The thrown exception is:

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'
InnerException: VssServiceResponseException: Method Not Allowed

StackTrace of innerException:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<HandleResponseAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__28`1.MoveNext()
```

We already checked and implemented some solutions found over the Internet but nothing is currently working. Would you have an idea of what is wrong or missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the SOAP object model in the [`ExtendedClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient) library for TFS 2013; TFS 2013 did not fully support the REST APIs used by the REST client.